# Advice on organizing sources and builds in C++ development under Linux (CMake as generator)

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

Can someone propose some good practices for organizing your source files and managing builds when using C++ under Linux. I use CMake to manage my builds although i do not use complex constructs at this point of time.
Let us say we have the following three scenarios.
1. For a makefile application to simply build a few executables from simple .cpp and .h files
2. For creating a static/shared library which uses other popular shared libraries say 
   OpenCV and OpenGL, for example.
3. More complicated types, for example, let us say we need to create an executable whose
   source files use  external libraries like OpenCV and also a custom static library that we 
   have built ourselves(for example, a custom static library with associated headers that we 
   built with step2 above).

I am sure many of you work on complicated  library projects where the build process is not that simple.  I am really looking forward to amazing answers from open source enthusiasts and hackers who contribute to open source projects. How do you guys organize your source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using CMake I would suggest using out of source builds (Either completely outside or in a `build` subdirectory of the project root directory) When using more than one configuration and/or compiler at the same time you can create a separate build directory for each one.

In the `CMakeLists.txt` in the project root directory I set up stuff that is to be used by all `CMakeLists.txt` files in the `src` subdirectory. I put all the sources for the executables and libraries in a `src` subdirectory and usually I group the sources that form a single library or executable inside their own subdirectory within `src` together with an accompanying `CMakeLists.txt` that describes how to build it. I usually don't separate include files from the sources.

I also have a `cmake` subdirectory in the project root dir where i put files specific to CMake like find modules and in my case a special cmake module which fixed the paths that the Eclipse IDE autodiscovers.

```
|--cmake
|  |
|  |--FindXXX.cmake
|
|--src
|  |
|  |--projectABC
|  |  |
|  |  |--CMakeLists.txt
|  |
|  |--library1
|  |  |
|  |  |--CMakeLists.txt
|  |
|  |--library2
|     |
|     |--CMakeLists.txt
|
|--CMakeLists.txt
|
|--build-release
|--build-debug
|--build-msvc-release
|--[...]
```

Comment: @trenki where do you put common header files?  Do you have an "include" directory under src?

Comment: @hopia: If at all I put _public_ header files for a library in an "include" directory at the same level as the "src" directory just as most open source libraries do it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest organizing sources by theme and having separate binary (or object) directories.  Header files and source files in the same directory.  One directory for each different compiler or platform:

```
Fields
 |-- src
 |   field_int.hpp
 |   field_int.cpp
 |
 |-- obj_linux_gcc
 |   |
 |   |-- debug
 |   |
 |   |-- release
 |   
 |-- obj_windows_gcc
 |
 |-- obj_visual_studio
```

In recent years at various shops, I have found that separating header and source files into separate directories, without regards to theme, is a pain to maintain and also takes a long time to become acquainted with.

"That's just my opinion, I could be wrong." -- Dennis Miller, comedian.